# How to optimize the stored procedure code

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which accepts 5 input parameters. The columns which the stored procedure returns is the same, but where condition changes according the params passed in.

Currently I'm using `if, else-if` to check for different conditions, and select the statements according to where conditions. Can anyone help me with other optimized way?

Update: now I have almost 14 parameters and check the conditions with all possible combinations. Is there any way in SQL for this check, apart from giving all conditions explicitly?

Here is the piece of stored procedure:

```
if(@OwnerWWID is null and @OwnerEmailID is null and @SourceURL is null and @ServerName is null and @Wave is not null)
begin
    select distinct 
        mp.Id, mp.SourceURL,.......
    from
        dbo.MPlanner as mp with(nolock)
    where 
        mp.MigrationWave = @Wave
end
else if(@OwnerWWID is not null and @OwnerEmailID is null and @SourceURL is null and @ServerName is null and @Wave is null)
begin
    select distinct 
        mp.Id, mp.SourceURL,.......
    from
        dbo.MPlanner as mp with(nolock)
    where  
        mp.OwnerWWID like @OwnerWWID + '%'
end
else if(@OwnerWWID is null and @OwnerEmailID is not null and @SourceURL is null and @ServerName is null and @Wave is null)
begin
    select distinct  
        mp.Id, mp.SourceURL,.......
    from
        dbo.MPlanner as mp with(nolock)
    where 
        ((mp.[Document Library Owner Email IDs] like @OwnerEmailID + '%' 
          or mp.[Site Owner Email IDs] like @OwnerEmailID + '%' 
          or mp.SourceURL like @OwnerEmailID + '%' 
          or mp.UserEmailID like @OwnerEmailID + '%')
         and DestinationType = 'sp') 
        or ((mp.OwnerEmailID like @OwnerEmailID + '%' 
             or mp.SourceURL like @OwnerEmailID + '%' 
             or mp.UserEmailID like @OwnerEmailID + '%') 
            and mp.DestinationType = 'odfb' and mp.OwnerJJEDSStatus = 1)
end
```

Comment: Why do you (think you need) other way  to solve this?

Comment: Each time I have to return the same select statement here. I'm changing the check conditions and where. Like If(param1 not null) , elseif(param2 not null)...... else if(param1 not null and param2 not null)... else if (param1 not  null and param2 not null and param3 not null).. All these checks return the same set of values with where statement matching to the param passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think understand why you want to change it. All of these if-else blocks start to become difficult to manage, especially if you later want to be able to change the procedure to filter on multiple parameters, not just a single parameter. The number of conditional queries explodes.

There *is* a way to do this with a single statement. It's the "optional parameter" pattern. It looks like this:

```
    select  ...
    from    dbo.MPlanner mp
    where   (@wave is null or mp.MigrationWave = @wave)
    and     (@OwnerWWID is null or mpOwnerWWID like @ownerWWID + '%')
    and     (@OwnerEmailId is null or ...)
    option  (recompile);
```

The pattern should be clear: If the parameter has no value, ignore it. Otherwise use it for filtering.

Be aware that while this can be a huge optimization in terms of code volume, it can actually be a *deoptimization* in terms execution performance. The `option (recompile)` is critical. Without it, SQL will generate a plan based on the first time the procedure is run, but obviously the plan to use in a situation like depends entirely on which parameters are set.

The option recompile tells SQL: "Hey, every time you run this statement, figure out a good plan based on the values of the variables that you see *this time*". So, if `@wave` (for example) is null for some specific execution, SQL can simply short circuit that predicate out entirely. If you only populate a single parameter with a `not null` value, only that condition will actually be tested.

Comment: Great to not only show the simplified code but also for calling out option recompile

Comment: This condition did not work in few scenarios,like in a where  "where ((mp.[Document Library Owner Email IDs] like @OwnerEmailID+'%' or mp.[Site Owner Email IDs] like @OwnerEmailID+'%' or mp.SourceURL like @OwnerEmailID+'%' or mp.UserEmailID like @OwnerEmailID+'%')and DestinationType='sp') or ((mp.OwnerEmailID like @OwnerEmailID+'%' or mp.SourceURL like @OwnerEmailID+'%' or mp.UserEmailID like @OwnerEmailID+'%') and mp.DestinationType='odfb' and mp.OwnerJJEDSStatus=1)" in this scenario, it is taking only the first condition .

Comment: You need to use parentheses to logically group your predicates

Comment: Mandatory links: 
1. Aaron Bertrand's [Kitchen Sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) 2. Gail's [Revisiting catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) 3. Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Comment: How can we get the count of the items according to this where condition passed?